# YQLResponseMalformedError: Response malformed on yahoo_finance?

Tags: python, ipython, yahoo-finance

yahoo_finance's get_historical function has been working fine for me until yesterday.

Now it just keeps giving me YQLResponseMalformedError every time I try to call get_historical. Any ideas? I literally did nothing new with the code.

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
yahoo = Share('YHOO')
yahoo.refresh()
yahoo.get_historical('2014-04-26', '2014-04-29')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
YQLResponseMalformedError                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-fbc20f9b6d26> in <module>()
----> 1 yahoo.get_historical('2014-04-26', '2014-04-29')

/Users/anjian/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yahoo_finance-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/yahoo_finance/__init__.pyc in get_historical(self, start_date, end_date)
    340             try:
    341                 query = self._prepare_query(table='historicaldata', startDate=s, endDate=e)
--> 342                 result = self._request(query)
    343                 if isinstance(result, dict):
    344                     result = [result]

/Users/anjian/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yahoo_finance-1.4.0-py2.7.egg/yahoo_finance/__init__.pyc in _request(self, query)
    123                 raise YQLQueryError(response['error']['description'])
    124             except KeyError:
--> 125                 raise YQLResponseMalformedError()
    126         else:
    127             if self._is_error_in_results(results):

YQLResponseMalformedError: Response malformed.
```

Comment: that's a bug with the Yahoo Finance API https://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance/issues/128, appears the Yahoo API may be slowly dying http://www.financial-hacker.com/bye-yahoo-and-thank-you-for-the-fish/#more-2443

Answer (score 1):

Answered here: [Python and Yahoo finance weird "YQLQueryError(response['error']['description'])" get_historical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149200/python-and-yahoo-finance-weird-yqlqueryerrorresponseerrordescription/44271722#44271722)