# Yahoo finance ichart service availability

Tags: python, r, matlab, web-services, yahoo-finance

Following [Has Yahoo finance web service disappeared? API changed? Down temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355075/has-yahoo-finance-web-service-disappeared-api-changed-down-temporarily)

Now seems something wrong with a ichart service too:
https://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=NFLX&a=0&b=1&c=2016&d=4&e=16&f=2017&g=h&ignore=.csv

[image: Yahooeyu]

Any news from `Yahoo!`? Closed by API key? Shutted down?

Comment: still down at 6:27 am est

Comment: I've suggested a workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149200/python-and-yahoo-finance-weird-yqlqueryerrorresponseerrordescription/44271722#44271722

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yahoo has officially confirmed that the Yahoo Finance API has been discontinued in the following thread in the Yahoo Help Community (see posts by username Nixon):

https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/Is-Yahoo-Finance-API-broken/m-p/250503#U250503

Answer (score 1):

There are already some excellent alternatives out there such as this:
[valueviz](https://github.com/robomotic/valueviz)

I was surprised because I was expecting at least a premium upgrade to retain some of the customers.
Not sure who calls the shots in Yahoo but not that clever!