# Yahoo-Finance module doesn't work anymore?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I've been using the yahoo finance module in python. I put the project down for the last couple months and just started it up again. Unfortunately it doesn't seem that there is anything behind the yahoo finance module anymore!

I run the sample code from the [pypi documents](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance) and get nothing back.

```
>>> from yahoo_finance import Share
>>> yahoo = Share('YHOO')
>>> print yahoo.get_open()
None
>>> print yahoo.get_price()
None
>>> print yahoo.get_trade_datetime()
None
```

Although I was able to open for GOOG I get an error when I try to access historical data, and cannot seem to access historical data for any stock.

```
None
>>> goog = Share('GOOG')
>>> goog.get_open()
'956.83'
>>> print(yahoo.get_open())
None
>>> goog.get_historical('2014-04-25', '2014-04-29')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\yahoo_finance\__init__.py", line 120, in _request
    _, results = response['query']['results'].popitem()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'popitem'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\yahoo_finance\__init__.py", line 123, in _request
    raise YQLQueryError(response['error']['description'])
KeyError: 'error'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\yahoo_finance\__init__.py", line 342, in get_historical
    result = self._request(query)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\yahoo_finance\__init__.py", line 125, in _request
    raise YQLResponseMalformedError()
yahoo_finance.YQLResponseMalformedError: Response malformed.
>>>
```

I've tried running with a more recent date range and no luck. Historical data seems to be simply unavailable from the module, where it was dependable just a few weeks ago. Any insights?

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149200/python-and-yahoo-finance-weird-yqlqueryerrorresponseerrordescription

Comment: I understand the workaround I wrote one just like it months ago. https://gist.github.com/Krewn/0e624d35c396df63262dd42d74f2beb6 
What I don't understand is why no-one is maintaining the python module.

Answer (score 1):

From Ed0906's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44050039/5766416

Yahoo discontinued their API for desktop connections. You can still connect to it via your phone. So one way you can circumvent this is by setting the headers of your GET request to some mobile browser.

OR

Follow Ed's method by getting and setting the crumb in your requests. I used it, and verified it works.

Comment: I'm not using the API directly I'm using the python module...