# <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>

Tags: python-3.x, yahoo-finance

I'm new to python and I need help.When I'm trying to get stock data from yahoo finance,I get this error.Here is my code.Thanks for helping.

```
from matplotlib.mpl_finance import quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
today=date.today()
start=(today.year-2,today.month,today.day)
quotesMS=quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl('MSFT',start,today)
attributes=['date','open','close','high','low','volume']
quotesdfMS=pd.DataFrame(quotesMS,columns=attributes)
print(quotesdfMS)
```

and the problem is at the line 6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URLError: <urlopen error \[Errno 11001\] getaddrinfo failed>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518528/urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-11001-getaddrinfo-failed)

Answer (score 2):

Old question, sure, but the answer is that the API this library depends on has been discontinued:

[Yahoo finance ichart service availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040042/yahoo-finance-ichart-service-availability)

A workaround is discussed here:

[Python and Yahoo finance weird "YQLQueryError(response['error']['description'])" get_historical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149200/python-and-yahoo-finance-weird-yqlqueryerrorresponseerrordescription/44271722#44271722)