# URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>

Tags: python, matplotlib

Just trying to get this code to run its very basic straight out of out of *Python for Finance*

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator,DateFormatter
ticker='AAPL'
begdate = datetime.date( 2012, 1, 2)
enddate = datetime.date( 2013, 12, 5)
months = MonthLocator(range (1,13), bymonthday=1, interval = 3)
monthsFmt = DateFormatter("%b '%y")
x = quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl(ticker,begdate,enddate)
if len(x) == 0:
    print ("found no quotes")
    raise SystemExit
dates =[q[0] for q in x]
closes = [q[4] for q in x]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(dates,closes, '-')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthsFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mondays)
ax.autoscale_view()
ax.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

when it runs i get this error:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)

    URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Comment: Can you tell us which Python version you are using? What is also the installed version of the libraries used? Do you have a slightly longer error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl` function with your parameters tries to get the values from `http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?a=0&b=2&c=2012&d=11&e=5&f=2013&s=AAPL&y=0&g=d&ignore=.csv` that does not work at the moment or anymore...

## Update

You could try with Value Viz as an experiment:

```
import requests
params = {'tickers': 'MSFT', 'date': '2017-06-09'}

r = requests.get('https://quantprice.herokuapp.com/api/v1.1/scoop/day', params=params)

print r.text
```

HTH

Comment: could you provide a way to perform this

Comment: Hi, apparently Yahoo dropped the support in May. Could you use some an alternative like [valueviz](https://github.com/robomotic/valueviz)?

Comment: thank you for the assistance. If you could please upvote the question it would be greatly appreciated.